# Are the AI Model's Form Processing inside power automate is provided as part of the office 365 licenses, or we need to pay extra fees

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow

We are planning to use the Form Processing AI model inside Power Automate >> now most of our users have E3 office 365 license, where they will be uploading documents to a SharePoint document library >> and then a Power Automate cloud flow will process the uploaded documents and extract the info and send them back to SharePoint.

But my question is: If the form processing capabilities are provided as part of the Office 365 licenses? OR do we need to pay extra licenses or fees to be able to use the form Processing AI model?

Answer (score 1):

To use AI Builder Form Processing model, you will need AI Builder license.

> AI Builder is licensed as an add-on to your Power Apps, Power Automate, or Dynamics 365 license.

**References**:

1. [AI Builder licensing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ai-builder/administer-licensing)
2. [AI Builder licensing FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq#ai-builder)

---

> Form processing has been released for general availability in AI Builder; therefore, it requires AI Builder capacity add-on licensing in Microsoft Power Platform.

**Reference**: [Form processing updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2020wave1/ai-builder/form-processing)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so are those licenses needed for all users who will be uploading documents to SharePoint? or for only one user which is the power automate service account?

Comment: If only one user is going to use the AI Builder model, it should work with single license.

Comment: do you know what is this calculator used for @ https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/ai-builder-calculator/?